# How to validate JWT using a public key certificate in Rust?

Tags: rust, jwt

I am using the [JWT](https://docs.rs/jwt/latest/jwt/index.html) crate to verify a token using a rsa public key embedded in the digital certificate.

```
use x509_certificate::certificate::X509Certificate;
use jwt::{AlgorithmType, Header, Token, VerifyWithKey};

fn main() {
    let certificate: String = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMII..........\nEND CERTIFICATE".to_owned();
    let x509cert = &X509Certificate::from_pem(certificate.as_bytes()).unwrap();

    let p_key = &X509Certificate::public_key_data(&x509cert);
    let token_str = "eyJhbGc..............";
    
    // How do I validate the above token with the public key?
}
```

JWT crate has an example in the documentation which uses [verify_with_key()](https://docs.rs/jwt/0.16.0/jwt/token/verified/trait.VerifyWithKey.html) function for this but it takes in a VerifyingAlgorithm as type. I went and looked at VerifyingAlgorithm [source](https://docs.rs/jwt/0.16.0/src/jwt/algorithm/openssl.rs.html#71-91) which has an impl for PKeyWithDigest where I think I can specify my public key. However, at this point I am getting a bit confused as to how to create a key of type VerifyingAlgorithm with my public key?

I also would like to know if JWT crate is the right choice for this or should I use openssl directly? It seems like openssl brings a lot of complications (from a little browsing I have done online). I just want to validate the jwt signature and read the token claims. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might consider using the [`jsonwebtoken`](https://docs.rs/jsonwebtoken/latest/jsonwebtoken/) crate instead. The API seems a bit simpler.

Comment: That relies on Ring crate which I am trying to avoid as it is not FIPS compliant.